# Android Studio No Input?

Tags: java, android-studio

I am practicing to build a calc app in Android Studio using Java. here's how it looks like
[Yes it is very simple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AT3a4.png)

Now instead of using buttons to enter numbers, I used two EditText views for entering numbers. now I wrote a method to add two numbers like this:

```
btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int result;

            first=Integer.valueOf(input1.getText().toString());

            second=Integer.valueOf(input2.getText().toString());

            result = first+second;

            value.setText(""+result);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please fill the both space with numbers", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
```

the code for adding numbers is fine but if I do not have an input in EditText views, the app crashes. I want to put the codes in an if else clause. if there are inputs in both spaces app does the operation but if not it makes a toast and askes for numbers from the user. but I have no idea how to code the if else conditions. anybody can help me?

Comment: `if(input1.getText().toString().isEmpty()) { ...}`

Comment: Provide your log cat error

Answer (score -1):

You can test if the input1 or input2 is empty as your if else testing criteria. The following code assume you have correctly found and initialized `input1` and `input2` editText views.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int result;
        Editable firstInputText = input1.getText();
        Editable secondInputText = input2.getText();

        if(firstInputText != null && firstInputText.length>0 &&
           secondInputText != null && secondInputText.length>0){
             first=Integer.valueOf(firstInputText.toString());
             second=Integer.valueOf(secondInputText.toString());
             result = first+second;
             value.setText(""+result);
        } else{
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please fill the both space with numbers", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Also for your calculator, you want to ensure the inputs are numeric strings. For your layout xml, you can specify it as follows.

```
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/my_test_editText"
    android:inputType="number"
    />
```

Comment: Your `if` conditions are inverted, they must be like `!=` instead of `==` & `&&` instead of `||`...or else convert the block of code from `if` to `else`